# Different sudo environment variables between ruby and shell

Tags: ruby, linux, shell

I'm writing a script that needs to be run with sudo, and have run into something curious and wondered if anyone could explain it...

My environment variable seems not to behave the same when in ruby vs when in shell:

```
user@server:~$ sudo echo $HOME
/home/user

user@server:~$ sudo /opt/ruby-2.1.2-p95/bin/irb
irb(main):002:0> puts ENV['HOME']
/root
=> nil
irb(main):003:0>
```

What could be the cause of this?

Edit: To clarify - I'm not asking why sudo is resetting my env variable, I'm asking why it does't when I run shell commands/scripts (1st command), but it does when I run ruby (2nd command) from the same shell session without any change in configuration.

Comment: `sudo` resets environment variables.

Comment: `sudo` executes the command as the root user, and `/root` is root's home directory. Why don't you expect `$HOME` to be updated?

Comment: You could try using the `--preserve-env` option, but it depends on the permissions enabled in `sudoers`.

Comment: sudo's environment variable handling is configurable to reset or not, In my case it's not getting reset in a shell or in bash scripts i run as sudo, but it is when I run a ruby script, which seems weird as I'd imagine ruby just to get the non-reset variable like everything else I'm doing in shell.

Comment: In your first command, `$HOME` is being expanded in your normal shell, not by the shell run by `sudo`.

Comment: Try: `sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: yup - that's it, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, sudo resets your environment variables.  You might be able to use sudo's `--preserve-env` (or `-E` for short) to preserve the environment.  You can run `man sudo` to learn more about sudo and its options.