# How can I simply redirect text containing $HOME into /etc/zshenv with sudo?

Tags: redirect, environment-variables, zsh, sudo

I want a script to set up a better (but non-default) location for my `.zshrc` file:

```
% sudo echo "ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh" >> /etc/zshenv
```

but this fails:

```
zsh: permission denied: /etc/zshenv
```

The problem is related to the redirection being done first, but there is no obvious way to solve this.  I can hear you saying 'use `zsh -c`' but that fails:

```
sudo zsh -c 'echo "ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh" >> /etc/zshenv'
```

results in `$HOME` being evaluated inside the shell launched with `sudo`, so my `/etc/zshenv` file contains

```
ZDOTDIR=/var/root/.config/zsh
```

Trust me: my home directory is not `/var/root`.

I tried [`--preserve-env`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36657864/241142) but that did not work:

```
sudo --preserve-env zsh -c 'echo "ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh" >> /etc/zshenv'
```

Obviously I can find a workaround for this, such as saving $HOME to a local variable in the script, but it seems like there must be a more direct and simple and straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I was thinking about the problem all wrong.  I want to prevent `$HOME` from being evaluated.  Of course escaping a single quote inside a single quote is a new kind of PITA, but here it is:

```
sudo zsh -c 'echo '"'"'ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh'"'"' >> /etc/zshenv'
```